# Обрезаный виджет

Tags: qt

Я создаю `QWidget`. Накладаю на нево `QVBoxLayout`. До `QVBoxLayout` додаю `QLineEdit`. Размер `QLineEdit` установляю таков как `QWidget`. При исполнении програми `QLineEdit` есть обрезаный. Почему?

```
class functionSticker : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTextEdit* text_description;


public:
    explicit functionSticker(const QString& text, QWidget *parent = 0 );
public slots:
    void resizeFrame();
};
functionSticker::functionSticker(const QString& text, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    text_description(new QTextEdit)
{
    text_description->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    layout()->setSpacing(0);
    layout()->addWidget(text_description);
    text_description->setText(text);
    setFixedHeight(100);
    show();
    connect(text_description, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this,SLOT(resizeFrame()));
}

void functionSticker::resizeFrame()
{
    int height = text_description->document()->size().height();
    setFixedHeight(height);
    text_description->setFixedHeight( height );
    updateGeometry();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите внимательно какому виджету какие размеры вы устанавливаете.

При использовании layout'ов родительский виджет сам подстроит свой размер под размеры содержимого.

```
FunctionSticker::FunctionSticker(const QString& text, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    text_description(new QTextEdit)
{
    text_description->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    layout()->setSpacing(0);
    layout()->addWidget(text_description);
    text_description->setText(text);
    text_description->setFixedHeight(100); // !<--------------
    show();
    connect(text_description, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this,SLOT(resizeFrame()));
}

void FunctionSticker::resizeFrame()
{
    int height = text_description->document()->size().height();
//    setFixedHeight(height);  // !<--------------
    text_description->setFixedHeight( height );
    updateGeometry();
}
```